# Better way to make an hamburger menu responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive hamburger menu for a project that has been assigned to me.
I've (kinda) managed to do it, but I don't actually know if the way I reached it is the proper one.

#### What I'm asking you

I've made two equals `<ul>`'s in order to hide one of them, when the dimension of the screen is above/under `700px`. 
I don't really like this solution that much, so I'm asking you if there is another way to "move" the content of navbar-desktop at the bottom of the `<nav>`, rather than copying it to `navbar-mobile` so that:

- I don't have to modify the content more than once
- I can clean the code and reduce the number of bytes to deliver into the net

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Prova Menu Hamburger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-logo">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/k63K1qXV/logoname.png" alt="Logo" width="200px"/>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-menu-desktop">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" lang="en">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="griglia-bottoni">
                <button id="bottone_carrello" aria-label="Vai al carrello per l'acquisto dei prodotti" type="button"></button>
                <button id="bottone_login" aria-label="Apri la pagina di login" type="button"></button>
                <button id="bottone_menu" class="hamburger" aria-label="Apri il menu" aria-expanded="false" type="button"></button>
            </div>   
        </nav>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-menu-mobile">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" lang="en">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
</header>
<main id="main">
    <p>Test test</p>
</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

`style.css`

```
/*Contenuti generici*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    background-color: #fffceb;
    /*font-size: 60%;*/
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body{
    min-width: 400px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

header{
    background-color: white;
}

/*Contenuti della barra di navigazione*/
#main-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.nav-menu-desktop {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu-mobile{
    display: none;
}

.nav-item {
    padding: 1em;
}

.nav-link{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #475569;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: #482ff7;
}

.nav-logo {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #482ff7;
}

#griglia-bottoni{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-menu-desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-menu-mobile{
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-menu-mobile.active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin:0;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}

.salta_link {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left : -9999px;
}

.salta_link:focus {
    display : block;
    position: static;
}

button{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#bottone_carrello{
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/F7WctjHX/tabler-icon-shopping-cart.png);   
}

#bottone_login{
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/HrrMTVrc/tabler-icon-user-circle.png);
}

#bottone_menu{
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/rzT55VP3/tabler-icon-menu-2.png);
}
```

`script.js`

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu-mobile");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", apriMenuMobile);

function apriMenuMobile() {
    hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
    navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}

const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", chiudiMenuMobile));

function chiudiMenuMobile() {
    hamburger.classList.remove("active");
    navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}
```

N.B: Please consider that the page I'm sharing with you it's really rude (only grafically, I hope), because I want to make it work firstly.
Since I'm almost new to this kind of developing, there are, for sure, better tecniques to reach what I'm aiming at.